# undefined local variable or method `simple' for #<#<Class:0xb4ec5284>:0xb44fae84>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Please I am new to Ruby on Rails and also new to stackoverflow. I am using the simple_form gem to create a Contact form where visitors will sign up for newsletter.
I have a Contact model and new.html.erb view file. The problem is I get the following error mesage when I navigate to the Contact link 
  "undefined local variable or method `simple' for #<#:0xb44fae84> " Please what am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using Rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.1
Thank you.

The Contact Model is in app/models/contact.rb as shown below.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

has_no_table

column :name, :string
column :email, :string
column :content, :string

validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :content
validates_format_of :email,
  :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500


end
```

and the view file in app/views/contacts/new.html.erb  is as shown below:

```
<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>
<h3>Contact</h3>
<div class="form">
<%= simple_form_for @contact do |form| %>
<%= simple.error_notification %>
<%= form.input :name, autofocus: true %>
<%= form.input :email %>
<%= form.input :content, as: :text %> 
<%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`simple` isn't a defined method, like the error says.

Use Simple Form's error notification method in your form:

`= f.error_notification`

Or, for better customization, add your own helper partial to render errors (I'm using the slim templating engine in this example):

**_form_errors.html.slim:**

```
- if resource.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    .alert.alert-error
      h2.error-header Please fix the following #{resource.errors.count} errors
      ul
        - resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          li= "* #{msg}"
```

**In your form**

```
= render "partials/form_error", resource: @contact
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I have corrected the new.html.erb view file as follows, "<%= form.error_notification %>" instead of  "<%= simple.error_notification %>" and I still have another error. "undefined method `type' for "string":String" Please what am I doing something wrong here again?